# What is the relationship between Safari and SSL certificates?

Tags: security, ssl

We recently updated the ssl certificate on our website and it works fine on chrome and firefox but when I use safari or edge on windows I get this error:

[image]

Any specific reason why this is happening, I manually removed the certificate and after that I visited the site again and didn't even save the certificate, why is that?

I had a look on the server logs, but couldn't find anything specific related to this issue.

This is what happens if I click on "view the certificate" :

[image]

Any help or input would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you get to see when you click on 'view the certificate'. What kind of error is being reported exactly?

Comment: I've updated the original question. Thanks.

Comment: Chrome uses the same certificate store as Edge on Windows, so I don't know why you didn't get the same error in all browsers (except Firefox, which has its own certificate store).

Comment: Revocation is handled either by downloading CRL files, or using OCSP, or consulting Certificate Transparency Logs. Browsers do not have necessarily the same behavior here, and hence the result can change. Besides you remove the essential piece that is the name or the certificate received, and since it is not about programming your question is unfortunately offtopic on this forum.

Comment: I just remove the domain name due to safety but here it is : engen.co.za. Thanks.